# What is the minimum reasonably supported GCC version?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11, g++

I have been developing a C++11 application against a modern compiler on my mac/linux, which works fine but then I tried to deploy it to a very old linux box (g++ 4.1.2: Feb 2007) and of course that's too old and the executable won't work.

This isn't surprising but now I'm wondering if there is a standard amount of time you are expected to support a compiler/standard?

I had a look around but there is no mention of this.. Should the support for a compiler version drop when the developers themselves deem it end of life and will not patch bugs?

Comment: This is largely subjective and easily dated: it does not make for a good SO question. (If wanting C++11 support, then it'll naturally require a newer compliant compiler.)

Comment: Define "support". It looks like you want newer features, which by definition come from newer versions.

Comment: The short answer to that question:  The compiler will be in use as long as someone is using it.  If you are developing for older hardware, for example, there are times where you don't have a choice but to use an older compiler.

Comment: It does not have to be a dated answer. There may be a URL to a chart of GNU versions under active development. If anyone is running a version of GCC that is no longer under active development it would be unreasonable for them to expect new software to work with it.

Comment: The GCC development team supports (actively maintains) a few releases (currently 4.7 and 4.8 — you can check at http://gcc.gnu.org/ any time you need to). Linux distros may well support older versions for longer.

Comment: Did you attempt to build the program on the ancient box with the ancient compiler from that box, or did you build it on the more modern box?  You can't necessarily run software compiled on a new platform on a machine running an older version.  If you compiled to a modern standard (C++11), then your 2007-vintage compiler won't have been prescient enough to have all the features you need.  If you'd coded to C++03, you might have been in with a chance (but C++11 is a better language than C++03).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: He said it's a C++11 application... but there's no reason the old box can't run a newer gcc version with C++11 support.

Comment: @BenVoigt: yes, he did say C++11 (I wasn't paying enough attention). The people who wrote G++ in 2007 weren't in the business of guessing what would be in the standard (that was a job for Boost).  You're right, there's almost certainly no reason why GCC 4.8.2 couldn't be compiled on the old machine using the GCC 4.1.2 to bootstrap the build. The only complication will be getting the standard C++ library installed correctly, and that's doable too.

Comment: Just require a C++11 compiler, this is a dependency not very different from others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're the one running gcc (or `g++`).  It's a *compiler*, used by *developers*.  End-user systems may not have any version of gcc.  It's `glibc` and `libstdc++` you need to worry about.  But in general, Linux does not aim for binary compatibility.  Do not expect any binary executable to run properly on any other distribution/major version.

Conversely, glibc and libstdc++ are careful to work with old kernel versions, so you should be able to install (configure+make+install) the latest runtime support libraries on your Linux box, and then build your application for that.

The easiest way to do that is probably to install the same distribution and version that your target has, into a virtual machine.  Then install the C++11 developer tools, and build your application.

Comment: Where can I find the oldest version of g++ that they are still patching bugs for?

Comment: @ElliotChance: Unless you are writing a source code library like Boost, you should be using the latest gcc.